# How do I get a String from UIPasteboard.value(forPasteboardType: kUTTypePlainText)?

Tags: swift, uipasteboard

[The documentation for UIPasteboard.value(forPasteboardType:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipasteboard/1622099-value) says, "For example, if the representation type is kUTTypePlainText … the method returns an NSString object".

However, on my phone, `UIPasteboard.general.value(forPasteboardType: kUTTypePlainText as String) as? String` is nil. It appears to return Data. So I made my code more elaborate:

```
if let text = value as? String {
    return text
} else if let data = value as? Data {
    return String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
}
```

If I copy plain text from a text field in a Swift app, it falls into the second code path, and returns the text as expected. But if I, for example, open Twitter and copy the link to a tweet, it falls into the second code path and String.init(data:encoding:) returns nil.

Am I misusing UIPasteboard? I thought that if you asked for text, it would give you text, but it doesn't seem to be filtering at all if I'm getting something other than UTF-8 from Twitter.

The app is built with Xcode 12.5 running on iOS 14.4.2.

Comment: You should be checking the types before fetching anything. Call https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipasteboard/1622077-types and see what you’ve got.

Comment: How do you know that what you have gotten is a String object that is encoded in UTF8?  How do you know that it's not an NSAttributedString object?

Comment: I don't know how it's encoded. If it's "an object in the pasteboard for the given representation type" and the given type is kUTTypePlainText, then per the docs, it should be an NSString, but it's inexplicably bytes.